# Which language or format Site Templates are in

Tags: site-template

I know site definitions are built using xml with different tags in them, but until now I thought Site Templates are in XML format as well containing latest settings of site definitions but in fact they are not, I tried to open file in NotePad and seen something like this,

```
'�p�8���1��P�3���(_o��w�7����[��j�=��
```

I wonder what language is it and how its stored in SharePoint Configuration Database of that specific web app.

Comment: I wonder where are these xml files located?

Comment: Above file is part of Web template which I downloaded from a solution gallery of a site collection with extension ".stp" it normallys gets stored in content db so maybe above language is something related to database way of saving contents of a site collection I guess :)